# the user cannot destroy a record in a rail 5 application after deployment with Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, capistrano3, puma

I have developed a very simple apps for trying out deployment on AWS server with Rails 5.0.0.1 and ruby 2.3.1.

As a user, I can delete a record without any problems on my localhost:3000. However I cannot delete a record after I have successfully deployed to a AWS amazon server with Nginx, Puma and Capistrano at 35.161.251.52/contacts, if you want to try. The destroy link becomes a show link.

I have followed this tutorial at https://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/

Can anyone shine a light on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Contact model is created with rails g scaffold, nothing fancy, just for trying out deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your javascript files have not been successfully deployed thus the handler that would handle the `delete` method of the link doesn't execute. Thus the link just makes a get request to its `href` and ends up to the show page.

Open developer tools from your browser and check if your assets are loaded correctly.

Comment: I thought capistrano was supposed to upload everything to the server automatically for me. If not, how can I upload javascript separately to the server?